# Should I want to install NPM for my Angular JS application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

I am new to angularjs.

Before I start my work, should I install NPM? If yes, why should I need to install NPM?

Comment: You need a server, if you want resources' paths to be working properly. 
If you decide to deploy a server on node, You need to install node.js. 
Although npm comes out of the box with node.js. You won't be needing that for angular dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While NPM is not necessary for AngularJS you can use NPM for creating advanced build setup for your AngularJS development. For example you can use Bower to manage version of AngularJS library and other plugins and addons related to it. You can also use the popular task runner Grunt that automates parts of your build process. Both Bower and Grunt are based on Node.js and require NPM.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install npm for angular. Angular can work without a server, but if you want to store data persistently and NOT use browser storage which doesn't offer the same power as a database, you'll need to set up a backend server which talks to a database or use a hosted service like **Firebase** or **Parse** (among others).

TLDR; If you include the angularjs script in your html file you can use it. NPM is for nodejs packages and you don't need it for front-end stuff typically.